# How do item qualities work for items purchased in the store?

Tags: mass-effect-3-multiplayer, mass-effect-3

In the multiplayer store, there are two item qualities mentioned; Uncommon and Rare. **Are there other qualities above or below these two? How do you know qualities the items in a pack are after purchasing it?**

Comment: The card is a particular color, silver for uncommon, gold for rare. I've also heard that the Spectre pack has exclusive items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are four qualities, common (blue border), uncommon (silver border), rare (gold border) and N7 (black border).

You can see all four of them in this screenshot:

[image: multiplayer items]

Comment: Also, the wording on the Spectre packs is "Rare or better..."

Answer (score 1):

there are only common, uncommon, and rare.
uncommon items have a silver outline and rare have a gold outline when shown in the pack contents. the rest, such as equipment, are all common.